# Need default Rally Kanban application to only display current iteration

Tags: rally, kanban

I need to modify the default Rally Kanban application to only display a chosen iteration. I put in a query iteration drop-down and then added :
                    //Build query based on iteration dropdown
                    cardboardConfig.query = dropdownIteration.getQueryFromSelected();
after the declaration of the config object in function displayBoard(). For some reason it is ignoring the query string. I have stepped through in the debugger and it is returning a proper value but the  board still always displays all stories from all iterations. I even just tried hard-coding in the config object 
query : 'Iteration = "March 2012"',
but that didn't affect what was displayed either, it still displays all stories from all iterations.
Any suggestions on what else to try or what else might be overriding the query string??
Thanks. Dax

Answer (score 2):

I dug more and if anyone else is trying to do this there is a line of code that overwrites the query in config Object in order to choose whether to display the last column. It completely overwrites any query param you set previously. Look for a line like :
if (hideLastColumnIfReleased) {
//                        cardboardConfig.query = new rally.sdk.util.Query("Release = null").or(kanbanField + " != " + '"' + lastState + '"');
                    }
If you comment this out or simply cat your new query string with this one everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The rally.sdk.util.Query object is documented in full here:
http://developer.rallydev.com/help/query

The query config property is documented in the Card Board component docs as well:
http://developer.rallydev.com/help/card-board